# Angular2 pattern validator on Input

Tags: regex, validation, angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to setup a pattern validator with the following regex :

- `^(((0|[1-9]\d{0,2})(\.\d{2})?)|())$`

[Try Regex here](https://regex101.com/r/hR3hI3/13)

That should allow me to get 1 to 3 digits, and then a decimal part of maximum 2 digits, and that should allow empty values as well.

The problem is that either my input is of type `text` and the validator is rejecting my input (any input since it's not considered as a digit I believe); or the input is of type `number` and without `step="any"` my input value is rejected if I have a decimal input (while the regex seems to be working on simpler values), and with `step="any"` it seems my regex is not working at all, allowing whatever value because of the `step`.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #bottleUpdatePriceForm="ngForm" >

    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let bottle of bottleArrayToUpdate; let i = index">
      <label for="bottlePrice">{{bottle.name}} : </label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="bottlePrice" autocomplete="off" step="any"
      [pattern]="pricePattern"
      [(ngModel)]="bottleArrayToUpdate[i].price">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <!--(click)="bottleUpdatePriceForm.reset();"-->
</form>
```

**EDIT :** adding my component code for regex binding

```
private pricePattern = /^(((0|[1-9]\d{0,2})(\.\d{2})?)|())$/;
```

Be it text or number I don't really care, I just need the pattern to work on my input... Any insight or something I am missing ?

Here is a working example in a plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/znVaS7?p=info

You can switch the input line in the plunkr to see the different cases :

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="bottlePrice" autocomplete="off"`

`<input type="number" class="form-control" name="bottlePrice" autocomplete="off" step="any"`

---

**Unrelated to the main issue :** Is there any way to call the form reset from the component rather than directly in the template ? 
`==> bottleUpdatePriceForm.reset();`

I was wondering, this is just for bonus.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please share the code line where you declare the regex? Just to make sure, could you also try `^(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})(?:[.][0-9]{2})?)?$`?

Comment: I added the code. Tried the regex, doesn't change anything. This is really a problem related to the Input type I believe

Comment: strange, I tried this, put up your setup and it worked fine. But regex is what it is, and it seems it sometimes works for some, but not for others :D You could try this: it might help, worked for me as well: so skip the pattern, just add `min="0" max="999" step="whatever you want here"` :)

Comment: Indeed, this does the trick, but I just wonder why my pattern is not working correctly with the inputs...

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, but most importantly it now works :) I'll put the solution up as an answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: I'll place an upvote for now, as I'm curious about the pattern : I'll probably need that later on and this little hack won't be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct solution for the not working regex, but this works with the same purpose. So remove the pattern and just change your input with `max` and `min` instead:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="bottlePrice" 
     autocomplete="off" step="any" max="999" min="0"
     [(ngModel)]="bottleArrayToUpdate[i].price">
```